# getting first day with STR_TO_DATE()

Tags: mysql

Given:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("March 03-06, 2015", '%M %e-%e, %Y') as date1
```

Instead of:

```
2015-03-06
```

I'd like to get:

```
2015-03-03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear there is no way to skip fields in format strings, only literals, but what we could do is pretend that the second day is actually a number of seconds:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE("March 03-06, 2015", '%M %e-%s, %Y')) as date1
```

The extra `DATE()` chops off the unwanted six seconds.

It's a bit of a hack, but it works... Tested out on MySQL 5.7.